# How to add a JCombobox in a JTable and fire its action inside of the JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Actually I want to add a JCombobox in a JTable and fire its action within the JTable.
I am using Netbeans, and I need to know where exactly I should put the code.
Thank you for your cooperation and time.
Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) to a [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) if you can follow this tutorial which describes how to [use a Combo Box as an Editor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox), another examples about `TableCellEditor` are [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table-Renderer-Editor.htm).